# Display dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling hard to get the table columns 'plaats', 'club' and 'matches' out of this array. Anyone? Thanks

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [nbr] => 1 
            [plaats] => Algemene rangschikking      
            [club] => 
            [matches] => 
            ) 
    [1] => Array (
            [nbr] => 2 [plaats] => 
            [club] => 
            [matches] => 
            ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
            [nbr] => 3 
            [plaats] => Plaats
            [club] => Clubnaam  
            [matches] => M  
            ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
            [nbr] => 4
            [plaats] => 1 
            [club] => K.DIEGEM SPORT 
            [matches] => 3 ) [4] => Array    
[nbr] => 5 [plaats] => 1 [club] => K.FC.ST.-LENAARTS [matches] => 3 )
[5] => Array ( [nbr] => 6 [plaats] => 3 [club] => FC.HELSON HELCHTEREN
[matches] => 3 ) [6] => Array ( [nbr] => 7 [plaats] => 4 [club] =>
K.FC.NIJLEN [matches] => 3 ) [7] => Array ( [nbr] => 8 [plaats] => 4  
[club] => F.C. ESPERANZA PELT [matches] => 3 ) [8] => Array ( [nbr] => 
9 [plaats] => 6 [club] => K.FC.DIEST [matches] => 3 ) [9] => Array ( 
[nbr] => 10 [plaats] => 6 [club] => FC TURNHOUT [matches] => 3 ) [10] 
=> Array ( [nbr] => 11 [plaats] => 8 [club] => K.VK.WELLEN [matches] => 
3 ) [11] => Array ( [nbr] => 12 [plaats] => 8 [club] => K.FC.EPPEGEM 
[matches] => 3 ) [12] => Array ( [nbr] => 13 [plaats] => 10 [club] => 
SC.CITY PIRATES ANTWERPEN [matches] => 3 ) [13] => Array ( [nbr] => 14 
[plaats] => 10 [club] => K.OVC.STERREBEEK [matches] => 3 ) [14] => 
Array ( [nbr] => 15 [plaats] => 10 [club] => K.VC.HOUTVENNE [matches] 
=> 3 ) [15] => Array ( [nbr] => 16 [plaats] => 13 [club] => 
K.VV.VOSSELAAR [matches] => 3 ) [16] => Array ( [nbr] => 17 [plaats] => 
13 [club] => K.ESK.LEOPOLDSBURG [matches] => 3 ) [17] => Array ( [nbr] 
=> 18 [plaats] => 13 [club] => K.RC.MECHELEN [matches] => 3 ) [18] => 
Array ( [nbr] => 19 [plaats] => 16 [club] => K.AC.BETEKOM [matches] => 
3 ) )
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Comment: *"out of"*: do you mean: *get removed from*, or are you looking to *get* the data from those columns.

Comment: foreach($data as $dat ){ ?>
    <tr><td>
        <?php echo $dat['plaats']; ?>
    </td><td>
    <?php echo $dat['club']; ?>
    </td></tr>
    
   <?php 

}

Comment: Results would have to be:
<table>
<tr>
<td>Value of plaats</td>
<td>Valua of club</td>
<td>Valua of matches</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: use some loop structure to access the inner arrays then use unset() to remove the elements... Then, if you mean you don't want that data to appear in the table, then simply don't echo them in the td's...

Comment: Thank you for the link. Got it now. Arrays always perplex me from time to time.